# Using variables as inputs in GNU parallel

Tags: variable, gnu-parallel

I want to use variables as input while passing the arguments in GNU parallel. For instance, I have three bash scripts that I want to run in parallel using GNU parallel

"par1.sh","par2.sh","par3.sh". 
my script look like this:

```
Filecount=$(grep -c "if" $1)

echo $Filecount

parallel -j0 sh ::: par$(seq 1 $Filecount).sh

mkdir $2
mv par$(seq 1 $Filecount).sh ./$2
```

I tried every possible way to run this code, but it is not working. Therefore, my question is how should I provide variable with GNU parallel. I also tried this:

```
par{1..$Filecount}.sh
```

But it is also not working, I also tried "seq" as well.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do, exactly? Are you building file names? Is that supposed to expand to `par1.sh`, `par2.sh`, ..., `parN.sh`? Can't you just do `parallel -j0 sh ::: par*.sh`?

Comment: It is usually helpful to describe how things are not working, because other users may be unable to reproduce what you are seeing. Are you getting error messages? Would you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/535892/edit) your question to include them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't with parallel but with the "variable" you're passing. This is what `par$(seq 1 $Filecount).sh` will expand to (assuming that `Filecount=10`):

```
$ echo par$(seq 1 $Filecount).sh
par1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.sh
```

You want it to work like a brace expansion:

```
$ echo par{1..10}.sh
par1.sh par2.sh par3.sh par4.sh par5.sh par6.sh par7.sh par8.sh par9.sh par10.sh
```

However, variables aren't expanded inside brace expansions:

```
$ echo par{1..$Filecount}.sh
par{1..10}.sh
```

The good news is that none of this is actually needed. You can do one of these:

1. Use normal globs

   ```
   parallel -j0 sh ::: par*sh
   ```

   or perhaps

   ```
   parallel -j0 sh ::: par[0-9]*.sh
   ```
2. Build the variable beforehand

   ```bash
   targets=""; for ((num=1;num<=$Filecount;num++)); do targets="$targets par$num.sh"; done
   parallel -j0 sh ::: $targets
   ```

So, using the second approach, your script would become (modified slightly to make it safe with arbitrary file names; not relevant in your case but it might be for future visitors):

```bash
Filecount=$(grep -c "if" "$1")

echo "$Filecount"

targets=( "par1.sh" ); 
for ((num=2;num<=$Filecount;num++)); do 
    targets=("${targets[@]}" par"$num".sh); 
done
parallel -j0 sh ::: "${targets[@]}"

mkdir "$2"
mv "${targets[@]}" ./"$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir $2
seq $Filecount | parallel -j0 sh par{}.sh';' mv par{}.sh ./$2
```