# How do I create a loop of variable length to print random numbers?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to create a matrix of random numbers after prompting the user for the number of rows and columns of random numbers. I can only use nested for loops.

I have created two variables: rows and columns but my main problem is getting the for loop to echo properly. Here's my loop function

```
    for i in [1..$rows]; do
    echo "$RANDOM";
    done
```

I have tried to increment the value of i with 1+1 but not matter what it only runs the loop once. I want the script to read the value of $rows.

Comment: How will you use the random numbers? If you want to use them where it is critical that they are good random numbers and not predictable from a simple pseudo-random generator, you should not use `RANDOM` but `/dev/urandom`. See `man urandom`. (Examples of critical usage: to generate passwords or encryption keys.)

Answer (score 11):

There is no syntax like `[x..y]`. You're probably thinking of `{x..y}`, but [that doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535895/22222) if either `x` or `y` are variables.

So, you could try one of these instead:

```
for ((i=1;i<=$rows;i++)); do
    echo "$RANDOM"
done
```

Or

```
for i in $(seq 1 "$rows"); do
    echo "$RANDOM"
done
```

Or

```
i=0 
while (( ++i <= rows)); do
    echo "$RANDOM"; 
done
```

Or even

```
i=0
until [ $i -gt $rows ]; do 
    echo "$RANDOM"
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Perhaps use the arithmetic conditional `while (( ++i <= rows))`

Comment: @glennjackman done, thanks. Is there any benefit to that apart from being slightly shorter than my `while [ $((i++)) -le $rows ]`? It does feel more elegant, but is there some other consideration as well?

Comment: Aside from the nicer syntax (less punctuation implies fewer errors), this protects you from some values of $rows: if rows is unset or empty, it gets value zero in arithmetic (with no `$`) -- unset or empty variable unquoted in brackets gives a syntax error (All variables in `[...]` should be quoted to protect from word splitting, filename expansion).

Answer (score 5):

As terdon [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584248/116858), the syntax you use is not correct, and he went on to give a few examples of loops that *would* work.

However, to print `$rows` number of random integers, you may also use

```
jot -r "$rows"
```

or, equivalently,

```
jot -r "$rows" 1 100
```

which will output `$rows` random integers between 1 and 100 inclusively (`jot` is available on BSD systems, or in the `athena-jot` package on some Linux systems).

Or,

```
shuf -i 1-100 -r -n "$rows"
```

which will do the same as the `jot` command above (`shuf` is part of GNU coreutils).

To create a matrix of `$cols` times `$rows` entries, you could use `rs` (`rs` is available on BSD systems, or in the `rs` package on some Linux systems):

```
$ rows=4
$ cols=6
$ jot -r "$(( rows * cols ))" | rs "$rows" "$cols"
37  29  2   74  5   14
82  86  74  63  73  9
58  10  14  96  12  90
98  13  55  56  40  52
```

Note that we need `$rows * $cols` random numbers. The example used here gets these from `jot`, but `shuf` could also be used (or any other command that produces the numbers).

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
$ eval print -C4 '$(('{1..20}', RANDOM))'
11190  17138  16156  5735
16751  13545  22647  13244
12925  11584  10984  32387
32093  8170   5305   6102
25136  30299  3944   9956
```

Or using GNU `shuf` to specify the range:

```
$ print -C4 $(shuf -i 0-99 -n 20)
96  55  93  33
25  7   19  60
34  51  88  46
79  13  70  98
63  37  69  41
```